# Unable to Install phppgadmin on ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: apache, postgresql, ubuntu, phppgadmin

I am trying to install phppgadmin on my ec2 instance which have ubuntu 16.04 and apache. The steps which I followed are :

1. sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-contrib phppgadmin
2. Edit /etc/apache2/conf-available/phppgadmin.conf and replace the line "Require local" with "allow from all".
3. sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/conf-available/phppgadmin.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/phppgadmin.conf

I have created vhost in my 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName abc.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.abc.domain.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        ProxyPreserveHost On

        # setup the proxy
        <Proxy *>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

As another application is running on my server so I have created vhost for that application. But Whenever I go to http://myserverip/phppgadmin it goes to my application running on port 3000. How to solve this issue, I don't know where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

apache will only react to the ServerName and ServerAliases in the HTTP header therefor entering http://myserverip/phppgadmin will return the default Vhost.

If you enter http://abc.domain.com/phppgadmin should lead to your application at http://localhost:3000

EDIT: 
The reason why apache proxies your other requests is the vhost finding process. 
Apache will go through all of Vhosts to find a fitting one, if this fails, it will choose the first one in an alphanumeric order, which is in this case `000-default.conf`. Therefore every request not fitting to phppgadmin is proxied to `localhost:3000`.

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html   for more informations.

Comment: But in my logs it is showing following such logs :
[Fri Jun 09 05:37:50.893835 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 5027] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3000 (localhost) failed
Currently the application which was running on port 3000 is stopped. So it is giving me apache service unavailable error. Do I need to add some configurations in apache  000-default.conf file ?

Comment: When I curl http://localhost/phpmyadmin on my server it is also showing me apache service unavailable error and logs are also showing the same thing.

Comment: execute this command `netstat -aln | grep '3000'. If this isn`t returning anything that means your application is not running

Comment: I know my application is not running but why ip/phppgadmin searching for the application running on port 3000. I understand if I go to abc.domain.com then it should search for application running on port 3000.

Comment: Then what should I do so that phppgadmin request not go to localhost:3000 ?

Comment: Add a `ServerAlias` entry with your IP as host to the phppgadmin Vhost

Comment: Where will it point to ? Can you site a sample entry for phppgadmin vhost ? It would be a great help to me .